# Regex for placing double quotes for particular field

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this:

```
String a = 'ABC(rfg) OR DEF(3dsgf56737(fg)sdg) OR KLM(dfgrg) AND DEF(ghthd)';
```

I want to place double quotes for DEF field alone:

```
String a = 'ABC(rfg) OR DEF("3dsgf56737(fg)sdg") OR KLM(dfgrg) AND DEF("ghthd")';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
String b = a.replaceAll("DEF\\((\\S+)\\)", "DEF(\"$1\")");
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: won't work if there are spaces in the brackets. If it's known that whatever's in the DEF(xxx) has no spaces then it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

What tools are you using to do this? sed? Python? Java?

A regex you could use with (eg) `sed` is:

```
's/DEF\((([^(]*|\([^)]*\))+)\)/DEF("\1")/g'
```

The `g` means match globally, and the bit in the `DEF` basically searches for matched pairs of parenthesis within the outer one (the `(fg)` in your example), or other non-parentheses.

Of course you would tailor the regex to your particular situation -- for example, if you only ever expect there to be alphanumerics and parentheses inside the DEF, then instead of `[^(]` you could use `[a-z0-9]`, etc.

@NullUserException's comment is still pertinent though - you tagged the question java and python but have not specified which tool/language you intend to use?

For example, you could use sed:

```
echo 'ABC(rgt) ... etc' | sed -r -e 's/DEF\((([^(]*|\([^)]*\))+)\)/DEF("\1")/g'
```

In any case, whether you use Java or Python, the regex I've given will be much the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java the result you want to obtain will not even compile

```
String a = "ABC(rfg) OR DEF("3dsgf56737(fg)sdg") OR KLM(dfgrg) AND DEF("ghthd")";
```

You will have to escape the " in the DEF as well, which can be achieved by slightly altering the regexs suggested above